# Find button in the ASPxGridView's DetailRow area

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have a nested ASPxGridView inside another ASPxGridView. The second grid is in the DetailRow Template area.

Based on the user's role I need to enable/disable buttons (on the server side).

I can find and then perform actions on buttons when they are located in the GridViewDataColumn area (see buttonDocumentTypeEdit and buttonDocumentSubtypeEdit buttons). I use OnHtmlDataCellPrepared event for that purpose.

But I cannot find the way to find buttonDocumentSubtypeAdd button on the server side, which is in the DetailRow area.

ASPxGridView:

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="gridDocumentTypes" ClientInstanceName="gridDocumentTypes" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                    DataSourceID="odsDocumentTypes" KeyFieldName="Id" Width="100%"
                    OnHtmlDataCellPrepared="gridDocumentTypes_OnHtmlDataCellPrepared">
    <Columns>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn Caption="Document Type" FieldName="Name"/>
        <dx:GridViewDataColumn Name="columnDocumentTypeActions">
            <DataItemTemplate>
                <dx:ASPxButton ID="buttonDocumentTypeEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit"/>
            </DataItemTemplate>
        </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
    </Columns>
    <Templates>
        <DetailRow>

            <dx:ASPxButton ID="buttonDocumentSubtypeAdd" ClientInstanceName="buttonDocumentSubtypeAdd" runat="server"
                            Text= "Add Subtype" AutoPostBack="False" UseSubmitBehavior="False">
            </dx:ASPxButton>

            <dx:ASPxGridView ID="gridDocumentSubtypes" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="gridDocumentSubtypes"
                                DataSourceID="GetDocumentSubtypes" KeyFieldName="Id" Width="100%">
                <Columns>
                    <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="Name" Caption="Document Subtype" />

                    <dx:GridViewDataColumn Name="columnDocumentSubtypeActions">
                        <DataItemTemplate>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding-right: 5px">
                                        <dx:ASPxButton ID="buttonDocumentSubtypeEdit" runat="server" Text="Edit">
                                        </dx:ASPxButton>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </DataItemTemplate>
                    </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                </Columns>
            </dx:ASPxGridView>
        </DetailRow>
    </Templates>
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

Server code:

```
protected void gridDocumentTypes_OnHtmlDataCellPrepared(object sender, ASPxGridViewTableDataCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.DataColumn.Name == "columnDocumentTypeActions")
        {
            var buttonEdit = (ASPxButton)gridDocumentTypes.FindRowCellTemplateControl(e.VisibleIndex, e.DataColumn, "buttonDocumentTypeEdit");

            //TODO: action
        }
    }
```

Comment: This code should work. I didn't find any issue on OnHtmlDataCellPrepared event.. See this [Find controls in the DataItem template of ASPxGridView column](http://developmentsolutionsjunction.blogspot.in/2011/11/find-controls-in-dataitemtemplate-of.html)

Comment: @Dimitri, if you are hidding or showing based on roles, you can set an On_Init event in your button itself, because your role will be there when the button is getting created